# Rigorous Proof that $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$

Tags: real-analysis

for my homework, I need to rigorously prove that

$$
(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2
$$

I asked my professor and she said we CANNOT just use the binomial theorem. I'm not sure how to go about this other than just using basic axioms.

Comment: So why don't you use the axioms? In any case there is an intermediate approach, namely foiling $(x+y)(x+y)\color{grey}{=(x+y)^2}$.

Comment: What about the distributive property?

Comment: You'll need to prove the distributive and commutative property for multiplication.

Comment: What universe belong $x,y$ to ?

Comment: Assuming $x, y, \in \mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field you can use the distributive property. You might find it helpful to use a substitution like $a = x + y$, because then you can say $(x+y)^2 = (x+y)(x+y)=a(x+y)$, from which point it should be clear what to do.

Answer (score 1):

http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/euclid/elements.pdf

Go to book 2 proposition 4 on page 53

Answer (score -1):

I concur with everybody above. (x+y)^2= (x+y)(x+y). Then, use the distributive property to find x^2+y^2= x^2+2xy+y^2.

Comment: You have not added anything new